Make div take up remaining space inside another div for text-overflow: ellipsis; to work
I am trying to make "cards" for my projects to show up on, and I want the description to show up but if it is too long I need the text to be cut off and .. be placed at the end. I cannot get this to work with "text-overflow: ellipsis;" however because the text just overflows like in the image below.

Here is my Code:


.project-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

.project-card .thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.project-card .thumbnail img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

.project-card .lable {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.project-card .lable .title {
    display: inline;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.project-card .lable .tag {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 2px 2px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    background-color: rgb(222, 224, 226);
}

.project-card .sub {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
<div class="project-card">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/50/50"></div>
    <div class="lable">
        <div class="title">Project</div>
        <div class="tag">v1.0.0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription</div>
</div>



Thanks for any help,
also sorry if this is a bad post as this is the first time I have posted.

For text-overflow: ellipsis; to work on one line, you need to set .project-card .sub { white-space: nowrap; }:


.project-card {
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

.project-card .thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    flex-shrink: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;

    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.project-card .thumbnail img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

.project-card .lable {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;

    gap: 10px;

    width: 100%;
}
.project-card .lable .title {
    display: inline;

    max-width: 70%;
}
.project-card .lable .tag {
    display: inline;

    border-radius: 2px 2px;

    margin-bottom: auto;

    background-color: rgb(222, 224, 226);
}

.project-card .sub {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    flex-grow: 1;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="project-card">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="thumbnail.png"></div>
    <div class="lable">
        <div class="title">Project</div>
        <div class="tag">v1.0.0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription</div>
</div>



If you want more lines to be visible, for example three, then do this:
.project-card .sub {
  overflow: hidden;
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp:3;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}



.project-card {
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

.project-card .thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    flex-shrink: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;

    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.project-card .thumbnail img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

.project-card .lable {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;

    gap: 10px;

    width: 100%;
}
.project-card .lable .title {
    display: inline;

    max-width: 70%;
}
.project-card .lable .tag {
    display: inline;

    border-radius: 2px 2px;

    margin-bottom: auto;

    background-color: rgb(222, 224, 226);
}

.project-card .sub {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp:3;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}
<div class="project-card">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="thumbnail.png"></div>
    <div class="lable">
        <div class="title">Project</div>
        <div class="tag">v1.0.0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription Realy Long Test String For Discription</div>
</div>



